# JQuery Mobile - Enable Form Elements after disable

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

In my Jquery Mobile form, the form  dynamically creates elements based on an Json Object. 
It dynamically adds an Edit button to the form. When the form is built, I set all elements to disabled.

How to re-enable form elements in Jquery Mobile ? (Not Jquery)

When a user clicks the Edit button, it should enable all form elements. Disable works just fine, but I cant get them to enable.

```
  for (var data_index in data) {
                    var item = data[data_index];

                    for (var key in item) {
                        var field_id = "fld_" + key;
                        // Build the Fields 
                        var $field_container = $('<div data-role="fieldcontain"></div>');
                        //var $field_set = $('<fieldset data-role="controlgroup"></fieldset>');
                        var $field_label = $('<label for="' + field_id + '">' + key + '</label>');
                        var $field_input = $('<input name="' + field_id + '" id="' + field_id + '" placeholder="" value="' + item[key] + '" type="text">');
                        $field_input.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        $field_container.append($field_label);
                        $field_container.append($field_input);
                        $view_detail_container.append($field_container);
                    };
                };
```

This creates form elements just fine, and they are disabled.

This snippet creates the edit button ( which adds to the DOM just fine), the code for re-enabling the form elements is in this event handler. All form elements are inputs.(basic text inputs)

```
var $action_edit = $('<a id="action_edit" data-role="button">Edit</a>');
            $action_edit.on("click", function (event, ui) {
                // enable all form fields 
                $('#detail_form').children().each(function () {
                    alert('clicked!') // fires everytime just fine
                    var child = $(this);
                    child.attr('disabled', '');
                    child.ready();
                    child.trigger('create');
                }).trigger("create");

            });
            this.AddAction($action_edit);// appends this button to the correct div.
```

Ive looked at the Jquery Mobile documentation, and seems to be better then it was, but it still needs better care.

- This [link is the form elements page](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/docs-forms.html) in the Jquery Mobile Documentation, if you search this page for "Disabling form elements", you will see a paragraph where they tell you to you :

> All jQuery Mobile widgets can be disabled in the markup by adding the
>   standard disabled attribute to the element, just like you would with
>   native controls. Each form widget also has standard disable and enable
>   methods that are documented with each form widget. Here are a few
>   examples of disabled widgets

IF you go to the [Text Inputs page](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/textinputs/) in the Jquery Mobile documentation and search the page for either  "enable" or "Disable", nothing is found. Furthermore, they are explained to be "methods", and no such methods by that name exist. All googling has had me try ...

child.removeAttr('disabled'); // no dice
 child.attr('disabled',''); // no dice

IS there something I missing because these are dynamic elements? Does the "page" (Jquery mobile, remember page is a div , and not a  document), need to be refreshed? another event on the elements?

Anything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While I was iterating on each element in the form, .each() only goes down 1 level. Given a JQuery Mobile form...

```
<form>
    <div class="ui-field-contain">
         <label></label>
         <input></input>
    </div>
</form>
```

You have to do a .each() on the child elements of the field container div.  Its worth nothing that doing the normal way of querying the dom for any input elements, and changing their attributes,  did not work either.

```
$('#detail_form').children().each(function () { 
   var child = $(this);
   child.children().each(function () {
        var sub_item = $(this);
        sub_item.removeAttr('disabled');
   };
};
```